# selenium hangs at find elements by class name with python

Tags: python, selenium

some places, where I'am using find elements, it hangs for 2-3 minutes (or even more). The page is loaded fully, there is no wait, it's only one line like this:

```
menu = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("text")
```

is there any way to avoid this long wait time or what could be the reason for that?
I'm using python 2.7, selenium 2.44.0 with FF 33.1.

thanks.

Comment: you say it hangs for 2-3 minutes.  what does it do afterwards? does it quit, or does it actually interact with the menu

Comment: after the 2-3 minutes menu contains the correct webelements (10 pieces).

Comment: what happens when you do this manually? does it take 2-3 minutes when you execute these steps manually?

Comment: yes, the same result

Comment: The single line in your example code does not show a situation where Selenium would actually wait. You use `find_elements_by_class_name` with `elements` in the plural. Selenium does not actually wait when you use any of the `find_elements...` (again, plural) methods. If there are no elements matching the query, then it *returns immediately* with a list of 0 elements. So you say you have code that is hanging for 2-3 minutes but you are not actually *showing* code that would hang for that long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there any way to avoid this long wait time or what could be the reason for that?

According to your comments, the app that you are testing is indeed **not** "loaded fully" (you confirmed that when you said it takes 2-3 minutes manually).

The only way to avoid this long wait time, is to improve the optimization of the app you are testing.  2-3 minutes is a tremendous amount of wait time, and any client that has to wait for that, will become very impatient.

The reason for the wait time is the app optimization (or lack thereof) or the server performance.  If you can improve these pieces, then the wait time will go down.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I built in a line that checks for complete:
    self.driver.execute_script("return document.readyState") == 'complete'

it hangs before the find elements, you were right.